# What is the typical RMS noise of a lithium battery?

Tags: lithium-ion, error, lithium, rms

Take a typical CR2032 battery, if it is not discharging, what is the typical variation in voltage over a short period of time (eg a few seconds or minutes)?

Comment: Are you looking for what the error might be in the expected voltage?

Comment: It sounds like the OP literally wants to know how stable battery voltage is when open-circuited and sitting there doing nothing. Little pertubations and the like. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yup, I'm interested in the nearly open circuited changes. What I'm trying to do is use it as a voltage reference for an ADC which will be used to measure thermal effects of resistors. I have other voltage references but their noise is greater than the thermal effect of the resistor. I could use a part like the LTZ1000 which has 1.2µV peak-to-peak noise and 0.05ppm/°C, but it costs $100. For my usage, I don't care about the exact value of the voltage, only that it remains stable over a few minutes.

Comment: for the sake of posterity, could you please change the question to use "noise" instead of "error"?  the battery has no "error" relative to anything else, it's just a battery being a battery, there's only electrochemical noise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently you are asking about "ECN", Electrochemical Noise, which is the source of RMS noise from Li-Ion primary cells, and all other chemistries. Quick Google search and some browsing of search results leads to the following scholarly article, ["A Method for Voltage Noise Measurement and Its Application to Primary Batteries"](http://jes.ecsdl.org/content/165/11/A2557.full).

They did several measurements, including CR2032 cells. The resulting noise is very small and needs special precautions to even measure it, a Faraday cage is a must, and uV-level [special instrumentation](https://www.gamry.com/potentiostats/interface-5000p/) was used to capture data. Here is one of their results, a typical waveform of noise, and its power spectrum:

[image]

By my eye-ball estimation, the RMS of noise of unloaded CR2032 cell is about 2-3 uV in 10^-2 to 5Hz range.

Comment: As the senior author of the manuscript, first, thanks for the plug :). Also, the black curve is really limited by the instrument, the battery noise is probably even lower than that unless the battery is disturbed in some way.